“Annotations.runbook” doesn't generate a link in a Slack message
In my k8s cluster, deploy kube-prometheus-stack, it is configured to send alert manager notifications to Slack. For some unknown reason, the Runbook icon is inactive and nothing happens when you click on it, although a page with a description of the event should open in the browser.
Here is a code snippet from values.yaml:
alertmanager:
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    route:
      group_wait: 20s
      group_interval: 4m
      repeat_interval: 4h
      receiver: 'null'
      routes:
      - receiver: 'null'
        matchers:
          - alertname = "Watchdog"
      - receiver: 'slack.alert'
    receivers:
      - name: 'null'
      - name: 'slack.alert'
        slack_configs:
         - api_url_file: /etc/alertmanager/secrets/alertmanager/slack_url
           channel: 'alertmanager'
           send_resolved: true
           title: '[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] Monitoring Event Notification'
           text: >-
             {{ range .Alerts }}
               *Alert:* {{ .Annotations.summary }} - `{{ .Labels.severity }}`
               *Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
               *Graph:* <{{ .GeneratorURL }}|:chart_with_upwards_trend:>
               *Runbook:* <{{ .Annotations.runbook }}|:spiral_note_pad:>
               *Details:*
               {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* `{{ .Value }}`
               {{ end }}
             {{ end }}

This is how the message in Slack from Alertmanager is displayed:A message in Slack from alertmanager
On the description page of kube-prometheus-stack I found the following comment: From 24.x to 25.x This version upgrade to prometheus-operator v0.53.1. It removes support for setting a runbookUrl, since the upstream format for runbooks has changed. But I don't quite understand how this affects the display of the Runbook link in slack.
